# Python: find average decimal year of two dates while ignoring NaT values

Tags: python, datetime

I have two datetime arrays:

```
index
0 2009-07-03
1 2009-07-03
2 2009-07-03
    ...
216426 2003-02-07
216427 2004-04-09
216428 NaT

index
0 NaT
1 NaT
2 2015-04-12
    ...
216426 2013-09-17
216427 2014-02-19
216428 NaT
```

How can I calculate the average decimal year of both arrays? If one of both arrays is NaT, then just take the non-NaT item at that index. If both indices are NaT, return NaT.

Comment: What format is being used for the data - are these Pandas Series or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution could be the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'index': ['2009-07-03', '2009-07-03', '2009-07-03']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'index': ['NaT', '2010-07-03', '2020-07-03']})

df1['index'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['index'])
df2['index'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['index'])

# Convert each date to a decimal year
df1['year'] = df1['index'].dt.year + df1['index'].dt.dayofyear / 365.25
df2['year'] = df2['index'].dt.year + df2['index'].dt.dayofyear / 365.25

df_years = pd.concat([df1['year'], df2['year']], axis=1)

df_years['average'] = df_years.mean(axis=1, skipna=True)

df_years['average'] = df_years['average'].replace({np.nan: pd.NaT})

print(df_years)
```

You can see that *NaT* values in the original dataframe are replaced with *NaN*.

The output from the code above is:

```
          year         year      average
0  2009.503765          NaN  2009.503765
1  2009.503765  2010.503765  2010.003765
2  2009.503765  2020.506502  2015.005133
```